# C++ count the number of digits of a double

Tags: c++, double, digits

i want to do what the title says like this:

```
int number1;
cin>>number1;
num1len=log10(number1)+1;
cout<<"num of digits is "<<num1len<<"\n";
```

but when the number of digits is 11 and more the answer is always `7(6+1)`

Does anyone knows why or what im i doing wrong?

Comment: I'm surprised you get an answer of 7 at all! The int will overflow and the actual value is a negative number - for which there is no log10(), the output should be "nanv".

Comment: actuall, Nim, the call to log10 will quietly convert the value to a floating point value - the definition is overloaded for double, float, and long double. See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cmath/log10/

Comment: @Ben Voigt: Technically, signed integer overflow is undefined behavior, regardless of how large the overflow is.

Comment: @Ben that is true, being lazy I only typed in 12345678912 which overflows to a negative number... but I think it highlights the point to the OP hopefully...

Comment: @ephemient: Technically, this isn't an arithmetic overflow, a conversion failure occurs in the stream extraction operator.  The standard calls for the result to be <quote>the most positive representable value, if the ﬁeld represents a value too large positive to be represented</quote>.  So I was wrong, it cannot be any representable value, and it especially CANNOT BE NEGATIVE.

Comment: Ah, I skimmed over the fact that it was C++, where `istream::operator>>` is friendly(ish).  C's `scanf` isn't defined to check for overflow.

Comment: Found out that C++03 and C++0x are different here.  In C++03, the value of `number1` is left unchanged if extraction fails, in C++0x then the closest representable value is stored.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is 'wrong' is the maximum value which can be stored in a (signed) int :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::numeric_limits<int>::max() << std::endl;
}
```

Gives me :

> 2147483647

Answer (score 8):

Floating-point data types, including `double`, store **approximations**.  What you're finding  by calling `log10` is the number of places *to the left of the decimal point*, which is affected by at most one by the approximation process.

The question you asked, how to find the number of decimal digits in a number stored in binary floating-point, is meaningless.  The number `7.1` has two decimal digits, however its approximate floating-point representation doesn't use decimal digits at all.  To preserve the number of decimal digits, you'd need some decimal representation, not the C++ `double` data type.

Of course, all of this is applicable only to `double`, per the question title.  Your code snippet doesn't actually use `double`.

Comment: That's true ... if the OP wants to count the number of digits in an integral value, s/he will have to take into consideration the max value his/her data type can handle.

Answer (score 2):

You are running past the unsigned 32-bit boundary ... your number of 11 digits or more exceeds 0xFFFFFFFF, and so wraps around.

You need to use either `unsigned long long` or `double` for your `number1` variable:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>

int
main ( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
  unsigned long long num; // or double, but note comments below
  std::cin >> num;
  std::cout << "Number of digits in " << num << " is " << ( (int) std::log10 ( num ) + 1 ) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Those large numbers will print in scientific notation by default when you send them to `std::cout` if you choose to use `double` as your data type, so you would want to throw some formatting in there. If you use an `unsigned long long` instead, they will print as they were entered, but you have to be sure that your platform supports `unsigned long long`.

EDIT: As mentioned by others, use of floating point values has other implications to consider, and is most likely not what you are ultimately trying to achieve. AFAIK, the integral type on a platform that yields the largest positive value is `unsigned long long`, so depending on the values you are looking to work with, see if that is available to you for use.

Comment: It does NOT wrap around.  Behavior is controlled by section `[facet.num.get.virtuals]` in the standard.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: Odd ... I did a test using `int`, gave it the number `12345678901`, and in the output to `cout` the number echoed back was `-1080488104`. Possibly a fluke from my compiler? Or is that just because that was how the value was stored when it was read in from `cin`?

Comment: @Will: I'm looking at the C++0x draft standard, and possible something changed since C++0x (the current standard that one would expect your compiler to follow).  Maybe I can dig up the current language.  Just to verify, you're reading the number from `std::cin` directly into a 32-bit signed integer variable, and not just doing `int n = 12345678901;` in the source code, correct?

Comment: @Ben Voigt: That's correct, exactly as my code example is above. I'm just curious since I do not work with `std::cin` all that often - mostly GUI apps, so input is usually from UI controls.

Comment: @Will: Found the section in C++03, and it is different.  In C++0x, `[facet.num.get.virtuals]` specifies that the result variable is left *unchanged* if conversion fails.  OTOH C++0x explicitly specifies clamping behavior.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: +1 for taking the time to look that up and teaching me something new. :)

Answer (score 0):

Others have pointed out that floating point numbers are *approximations*, so you can't really get an accurate count of digits in it.

But...you can get something approximate, by writing it out to a std::stringstream object, then converting it to a std::string, and getting the lenght of the said string. You'll of course have to deal with the fact that there may be non-digit characters in the string (like minus sign, decimal point, E for exponent etc). Also the number of digits you obtain in this manner would be dependent on formatting options you choose when writing to the stringstream object. But assuming that you know what formatting options you'd like to use, you can get the number of digits subject to these options.